# A theory about a travelling wave due to a vibrating rope seems to be contradictory, please spot what is wrong?

Tags: waves

Consider a travelling wave produced by vibrating one end of a rope while the other end is made to freely move along a vertical line. Mathematically, the equation of the traveling wave that also represents the equation of motion of each point on the rope is given as follows.

$$y(x,t)=A\sin(kx-\omega t)$$

In the book I read, a certain particle on the rope moves up and down perpendicular to the propagation vector as wave does not transfer material but energy.

I don't agree with the statement that "a certain particle on the rope moves up and down perpendicular to the propagation vector". It is because I think to maintain the same point on the rope to move up and down, the arc length of $y(x,t)$ must be equal to that of $y(x,t+\Delta t)$ for $0\leq x \leq a$ and any $\Delta t$. However, according to the Notes below, their arc length are not generally equal.

[image]

From the figure above, how can $P$ and $Q$ be the same point of the rope while the red and blue curves have different length?

So my question are: **Does each point of the rope move up and down?**

### Notes

From $x=0$ to $x=a$, generally the arc length of $y=\sin x$ is not equal to that of $y=\sin(x-x_0)$.

Let $S(x_0)$ be the arc length of $y=\sin(x-x_0)$ for the given interval.

\begin{align}
S(x_0) &= \int_0^a\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\, \textrm{d}x\\
       &= \int_0^a\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x-x_0)}\, \textrm{d}x\\
\end{align}

If $S(0)=S(x_0)=\text{const}$ for any $x_0$ then $\frac{\textrm{d}S(x_0)}{\textrm{d}x_0}=0$. Thus I have to check whether or not $\frac{\textrm{d}S(x_0)}{\textrm{d}x_0}=0$.

\begin{align}
\frac{\textrm{d}S(x_0)}{\textrm{d}x_0}
&= \frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x_0}\int_0^a\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x-x_0)}\, \textrm{d}x\\
&= \int_0^a\frac{\textrm{d}\left(\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x-x_0)}\right)}{\textrm{d}x_0}\, \textrm{d}x\\
&= \int_0^a\frac{\cos(x-x_0)\sin(x-x_0)}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x-x_0)}}\, \textrm{d}x\\
&= \int_{-x_0}^{a-x_0}\frac{\cos y\sin y}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2y}}\, \textrm{d}y\\
&= \sqrt{1+\cos^2 x_0}-\sqrt{1+\cos^2(a-x_0)}\\
&\not = 0
\end{align}

It implies that generally they are not equal.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be focusiing on the change in length as a problem, but really it is not.

The force which causes the rope to return is an *elastic force*. Just as with a spring it tries to return to it's original shape because *it has been deformed*.

Yes, it is generally discussed in term of tension in the rope, but what is tension if not the elastic forces between the molecules of the fibers. Keep in mind that *all* materials stretch a little under tension. It's not much in a natural fiber rope, but it is some---ask anyone who has ever tried to walk a taunt-line.

It is also worth being aware that

- Diagrams in texts generally use a very exaggerated transverse scale.
- The claim of purely transverse motion depends on small displacements
- Demos where a real rope is driven by a wheel, *do* introduce some longitudinal motion

Comment: So a certain point on the rope will oscillate in both x and y directions, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be answered with an animated gif:

[image]

Clearly the nodes (red dots) are stationary, as are each point if you drop a perpendicular line (like a ruler) onto your screen.

Now obviously this isn't *exactly* what you have because there is a fixed end on the right. But if you put your hand over the right end, you'll see the same thing as a the free end. [Or you can click this link](http://zonalandeducation.com/mstm/physics/waves/standingWaves/understandingSWDia3/UnderstandingSWDia3.html) and watch the wave go (I suggest going to the 5th or 7th harmonic).

Comment: It is a stationary wave (rather than a single travelling wave) and how can the rope changes its length if the rope is not stretchable?

Comment: Can you make a wave with an unstretchable rope?

Comment: Then ropes should not be used to illustrate the travelling wave.

Comment: That is one persons opinion. I think it's a fine example because you can clearly see the waves in it. It's a lot more difficult to show waves by using pistons to compress a gas...